# SQL database tag request

Tags: sql, database, tags

I have a photo table which looks like this:

```
id  title      rating  photopath
1   myself     7.0     /photopath1.jpg
2   cat        8.0     /photopath2.jpg
3   dog        6.0     /photopath3.jpg
4   girlfriend 5.0     /photopath4.jpg
```

and a tag table:

```
id  tag_name   photo_id
1   selfie     1
2   sun        1
3   nature     2
4   relax      2
5   loyal      3
6   journal    3
7   selfie     4
8   sun        4
9   problems   4
```

And I want to call all photos that have the tags "selfie" and "sun". How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select p.*
  from photo p
  join (select p.id
          from photo p
          join tag t
            on p.id = t.photo_id
         where t.tag_name in ('selfie', 'sun')
         group by p.id
        having count(*) = 2) x
    on p.id = x.id
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5c95c2/2/0

Output:

```
| ID |      TITLE | RATING |       PHOTOGRAPH |
|----|------------|--------|------------------|
|  1 |     myself |      7 | /photograph1.jpg |
|  4 | girlfriend |      5 | /photograph4.jpg |
```

Comment: IN ('selfie', 'sun') evaluates as `tag_name = 'selfie' OR tag_name = 'Sun'`, OP wants where Both are present.

Comment: That's why I use the HAVING clause, where count is equal to 2. It is not either or, but both, the way that I've written it.

Comment: @M.Ali maybe you meant to put that comment under JammoD's answer, which is either/or

Comment: Would like to give you more props because of your accurate answer and demonstration. I will use the reply from Gordon though, because as he said it will be easier to delete or add the bottom query more conditions, as he pointed out.

Comment: @AlfonsoFernandez-Ocampo unless you plan to have exclusions -- and are only searching on tags that are included -- the only thing you do to the above is add the word to line 7 of the sql, and the count(*) to the total # of keywords (as opposed to adding entire case statements), so I would think it is easier. Also you have to join back to the original table anyway to get the additional fields (title, rating, photo)

Comment: Ok you won this one. lulz

Answer (score 2):

This is a "set-within-sets" query.  I like to solve these using aggregation and `having`:

```
select p.id
from photos p join
     tags t
     on p.id = t.photo_id
group by p.id
having sum(case when tag_name = 'selfie' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when tag_name = 'sun' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

The convenience of this method is that it is easy to add more conditions (such as another tag) or to invert a condition (such as "selfie"s without "sun").

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM Photos
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Tag_Table
              WHERE photo_id = Photos.id
               AND tag_name = 'selfie'
             )
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Tag_Table
              WHERE photo_id = Photos.id
               AND tag_name = 'Sun'
             )
```